# Structure and layout style.css for site-header, site-inner, and site-footer problem in wordpress genesis

Tags: css, wordpress-theming

Help. I can't seem to show the border and margin in wordpress genesis sample theme. In style.css, I've entered this code but when I refreshed in chrome wordpress,  none show up. I've inspect elemented and confirmed that the html structure has .site-header .site-inner .site-footer. What is wrong with my code????

Chrome browser running wordpress 5.

```
.site-header,
.site-inner,
.site-footer {
border: 3px solid #000;
margin: 2 auto;
max-width: 1300px;}
```

I should show some borders and margins.

Comment: Sounds like a caching issue. Try `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `R`.

Comment: If this is a cache problem, there is a hard-reload too. Press F12 (to open developer console) and then right-click on regular Reload icon... There will be 3 options. The third one is even "harder" than CTRL+SHIFT+R.

Comment: add "!important". ...eg-   border: 3px solid #000 !important;   max-width: 1300px  !important;

Answer (score 0):

add " !important ". (Your css class override important.)

> eg-

```
.site-header,
.site-inner,
.site-footer {
border: 3px solid #000 !important;
margin: 2 auto !important;
max-width: 1300px !important;}
```